# Не отправляться письмо, не приходит письмо. feedback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Пытаюсь реализовать "обратную связь", но что-то не получается, и я не могу понять в чём проблема.

Использую гем gem [pointless_feedback](https://github.com/vigetlabs/pointless-feedback/)

Может я не правильно понял как настроить:

```
PointlessFeedback.setup do |config|
  # ==> Feedback Configuration
  # Configure the topics for the user to choose from on the feedback form
  # config.message_topics = ['Error on page', 'Other']

  # ==> Email Configuration
  # Configure feedback email properties (disabled by default)
  # Variables needed for emailing feedback
  config.email_feedback            = true
  config.send_from_submitter       = true
  config.from_email                = 'feedback@pointlesscorp.com'
  config.to_emails                 = ['adacer91092@mail.ru', 
                                    'adacer73044210@gmail.com']
  # config.google_captcha_site_key   = nil
  # config.google_captcha_secret_key = nil
end
```

Логи:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Gemfile

```
gem 'pointless_feedback'
```

Gemfile.lock

```
pointless_feedback (4.0.5)
  rails (>= 4.0)
  typhoeus (~> 0.7, >= 0.7.3)
```

Comment: Так а что именно не получается? Глядя в логи: pointless_feedback_message создаётся без ошибок, почта отправляется. Реальное письмо в дев окружении не приходит - так это совершенно нормально. Поставьте letter_opener или mailcather, чтобы "получать" письма в девелопменте

Comment: Спасибо большое, сейчас попробую.